# Declaração de um array global de estruturas em C

Tags: c, array, variáveis, struct, global

Criei uma estrutura `cliente` e a ideia seguinte seria criar um *array* `clientes`.
A minha ideia seria declarar o *array* `clientes` de forma global, para que todas a funções possam interagir sem que estar sem a passar como parâmetro de entrada. Mas como sou muito iniciante não sei se é uma boa prática.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você é iniciante acho melhor usar o parâmetro mesmo, você pode se perder para controlar esse variável global. Outra dica que eu do, pesquise sobre "estruturas"(struct) é meio simples de entender e acho que fica mais organizado. Pois você pode definir bem sem precisar se preocupar demais.

Answer (score 1):

De forma geral não, o correto é passar tudo como parâmetro, tudo que é global acaba se perdendo na organização. Claro, para algo simples não dará problema e pode dar a falsa sensação de segurança, mas quando começa fazer códigos reais vai ficando complicado, então aprenda fazer da forma correta desde o começo. Isto independe do seu problema. É raro precisar de algo global e precisa ter bom domínio da programação para usar adequadamente. Na dúvida use parâmetros.